# What's wrong with this simple php code querying a database and displaying results?

Tags: php, html

This is simply additional functionality for an assignment where I have created a water level monitor device. All I want the web page to do is display a couple of SQL results. However, none of the PHP in the page seems to run at all. I have tested the SQL statements and they work fine so it is definitely my PHP. Any help would be appreciated, cheers!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='cs' lang='cs'>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv='Content-Language' content='cs' />   

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styl.css" type="text/css" />

<title>Flood Detector</title>

<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$con=mysqli_connect("");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header"> 
<h2><a href="#" title="home">Flood Detector</a></h2>
<ul id="menu-top">
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="topten.html">Records</a></li>   
</ul>
</div>
<div id="contain"> 
  <div id="left"> 
   <h1>Welcome</h1>
   <p> Your water levels are currently <?php

    $sql = "SELECT BODY FROM sms ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)
    or die(mysqli_error($con));

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    print_r($row);

    ?></p>

    <br>
    <br>

    <p> Your water has reached dangerous levels <?php 

    if ($dangerresult = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sms WHERE BODY = ' warning'")) {
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($dangerresult);
    echo $count;
    }

    ?>
    times
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="cleaner"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to fetch the results using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: Do you have PHP installed and configured correctly? Are you calling localhost in the url you're requesting through your web browser? Do webserver logs show any errors?

Comment: `$mysqli_query` is a variable, `mysqli_query` is a function

Comment: Pass DB connection to your queries, *done like dinner.* Do that, and wonderful things will start to happen.

Comment: whats this , I meant wher it is defined $dangerresult

Comment: But then this, `if ($dangerresult = $mysqli_query` now that's an issue. I have no idea what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @ProgrammingStudent The mysql_* functions are deprecated, and are from a different PHP extension than the mysqli_* functions used here.

Comment: @MarkBaker It's hosted on my university's web server. I doubt I have permissions to go through their logs :P.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the dangerresult part is supposed to look up all records containing " warning" in the BODY field and count them before displaying the number. Any better ways welcome!

Comment: Why are you doing `echo $result;`? Here, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`. What the other person who answered below did not state, is what I said above; you need to pass DB connection to your query. Plus, the `$mysqli_query` remove the dollar sign (it's a function, not a variable), and pass DB connection to that query also. Error reporting will tell you that `$mysqli_query` is an unassigned variable.

Comment: Ok, well you're not using `mysqli_num_rows()` correctly, Plus, the space in `' warning'` isn't helping neither. I might put in an answer if nobody can help.

Comment: @Fred-ii- how do you know the space in ' warning' is a problem? He says the SQL itself works, so it may be correct.

Comment: Okay, I knew there was a fair bit to fix when I submitted this but hold on a sec and I'll update the code to what it is now. It's still not working but it'll give you a better idea of what I have changed based on yours and other peoples' answers. Unsure whether you wanted me to put error_reporting after all php tags or all of them.

Comment: @Frustrated_Scotsman the error reporting bit should be put at the beginning and only once (and be commented out in production). PHP will hide error reporting by default, so enabling it while fixing code is pretty much necessary.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the space in " warning" is intentional. Code updated.

Comment: @Frustrated_Scotsman I've posted my answer below. Keep me posted. We'll get 'er done ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to pass DB connection to your queries.

You also have a space in `' warning'` so that may cause problems; **remove it**  `'warning'` if you're not getting results with my answer/code below.

```
$sql = "SELECT BODY FROM sms ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    echo $result;
```

**Sidenote:** I don't know why you're doing `echo $result;` so you may need to elaborate on that.

Or try something like:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "Your water levels are currently " . $row['BODY'];
  echo "<br>";
  }
```

and `$mysqli_query` that is a function not a variable.

In regards to `mysqli_num_rows()`, try using it this way, since you want to check if `num_rows()` does return a value as per the word you're looking for, being "warning".

```
$dangerresult = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sms WHERE BODY = ' warning'");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($dangerresult);

if($count > 0){
    echo $count;
}
else{
    echo "Empty.";
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Or try:

```
$dangerresult = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sms WHERE BODY = 'warning'");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($dangerresult);

if($count > 0){
    echo $count;
}
else{
    echo "Empty.";
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dangerresult))
  {
  echo "Your water levels are currently " . $row['BODY'];
  echo "<br>";
  }
```

- Also add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to all the `mysqli_query()` and error reporting.

Plus, in regards to SQL injection,  [**use `mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Comment: He wasn't using `mysqli_num_rows()` incorrectly, but was not printing a number for the case of a failed query.

Comment: echo $result was simply attempting to get it to write it onto the screen. How would I go about doing this? Example output: "Your water levels are currently $result" In this case it wouldn't make sense if it said "warning" but surely str_replace would sort that out.

Comment: @Frustrated_Scotsman I would need to know what the column name is called that holds the user's water levels. That also needs to be added to the query in the SELECT. The `while` loop is to take care of that. If you're only selecting BODY from the query, then it will only echo that in the loop. You'd need to add the column for the level.

Comment: It's BODY. The water levels are stored as one of three states in the DB, "safe", "worrying" and well, "warning" but I would replace that with "dangerous" or "critical".

Comment: @Frustrated_Scotsman If what you have in your DB is "warning" without a space, then your WHERE clause cannot contain a space, that's why it's not returning a result. It needs to be `WHERE BODY = 'warning'` and not `WHERE BODY = ' warning'`. I will make a quick edit to add to the `while` loop to echo "Your water levels....". Edit: modified to read as `echo "Your water levels are currently" . $row['BODY'];`

Comment: I made the changes you stated above. However, now the site still says nothing for the first part yet the dangerresult part now says this "Your water has reached dangerous levels 0){ echo $count; } else{ echo "Empty."; } ?> times"

Comment: @Frustrated_Scotsman I've made another edit. Reload and look under **Edit:**. You want to count the times? You said "BODY" contains text, right? "safe", "worrying" and well, "warning". Counting stuff is a different thing.

Comment: @Frustrated_Scotsman You're saying that it's showing as "code" `"Your water has reached dangerous levels 0){ echo $count; } else{ echo "Empty."; } ?> times"`? If so, then that tells me that you're probably not running this as a `.php` file extension. Is the file you're running `.html`?

Comment: Yes, but when I looked up tuts on how to use php and html together they all said it was fine just to chuck php in wherever and it would run :/. It seems strange that it would only start writing out the code partway through an if statement, why would that be?
I really am sorry about all of this. I'm an ethical hacking student, not web dev!

Comment: @Frustrated_Scotsman Tuts didn't give you the right time of day in regards to that. Sure, you can run `.html` as PHP, just as long as you instruct Apache/server to handle `.html` files as PHP (done in `.htaccess`, but that can be a wee bit of a pain; it's best to just use a `.php` extension. There's nothing wrong in having HTML inside a PHP file, just as long as you don't inject pure HTML into PHP and vice-versa. You do HTML, then `<?php // some code ?>` then back into HTML.

Comment: Ah, I see. So how then, would I sort this mess out as it is pretty much half and half?.

Comment: @Frustrated_Scotsman Keep what you have now, it's fine. But, you're not getting results back with what I posted in my answer? Did you rename your file to `.php`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes! http://imgur.com/rRD0LVG I thought it hadn't as I stupidly clicked refresh rather than changing the url to .php after uploading. It's not pretty but it will do the trick! Thank you so much. Now, as you'll see, there's a link to a "Records" page that I now need to fix! I'm pretty sure I can manage based on the information you have given me. All it does is display the last 10 entries to the DB. Thanks again.

Comment: @Frustrated_Scotsman Aye, that's great! Glad to hear it worked out. *Cheers* and you're quite welcome.

Comment: @Fred-ii- http://imgur.com/P65L4Sk Ugly as sin but works perfectly for a proof-of-concept and only took 5 minutes to fix. You're a legend mate. If I were flush for cash I'd send you a Christmas present haha. From now on I think I'll stick to my PYTHON and C. This PHP malarky just isn't for me.

Comment: @Frustrated_Scotsman Doesn't look so bad. A bit of CSS will pretty that up in no time mate! Just making a Scotsman smile, is Xmas enough for me ;) One of my best mates is a Scot and plays the pipes too, full suit 'n all, love it :) All the best mate, *cheers!* - PHP isn't so bad once you've told it who's the boss ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's a module on Mobile Phone Technologies. My lecturer won't even be looking at the design, just functionality for a bit of extra credit. The real magic of the project takes place between an Arduino and my phone. How much more stereotypical can you get?! haha take it easy buddy

Comment: @Frustrated_Scotsman Very cool, gotta love the magic ;) Take it easy too buddy, *cheers* - P.s.: We'll need to stop chatting here, the moderators don't really like that if it's considered off-topic, and will probably clear out all the comments they see as being too chatty. Just giving you the "right time of day" mate, *cheers* and enjoy! ciao ;)

Answer (score 0):

You did not use mysqli_select_db and mysqli_fetch_array function to fetch data. Please try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='cs' lang='cs'>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv='Content-Language' content='cs' />   

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styl.css" type="text/css" />

<title>Flood Detector</title>

<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("*****************","*********","********","***********");


    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
?>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header"> 
  <h2><a href="#" title="home">Flood Detector</a></h2>
  <ul id="menu-top">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="topten.html">Records</a></li>  
 </ul>
</div>
<div id="contain"> 
  <div id="left"> 
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p> Your water levels are currently <?php

    $sql = "SELECT BODY FROM sms ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($sql);
    //echo $result;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
         print_r($row);
    }
    ?></p>

<br>
<br>

<p> Your water has reached dangerous levels <?php 

    if ($dangerresult = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM sms WHERE BODY = ' warning'")) {
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($dangerresult);
    echo $count;
    }

    ?>
    times
</p>
</div>

<div class="cleaner"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Double check your answer.

Comment: Just tried it and it still doesn't work. Even if I put something like
echo "hello";
it won't display

Comment: As per your edit, it's still wrong. Plus, you're doing the same error as the OP; variable instead of a function.

Comment: @Frustrated_Scotsman you also not select database selection function. Please check I have updated my code.

Comment: @VijayVerma OP is choosing DB, it's the 4th parameter in `$con=mysqli_connect("*****************","*********","********","***********");` - Plus, `mysqli_select_db("*******", $con);` connection comes **first**, so you're wrong on that point also. This isn't `mysql_` method.

Answer (score 0):

There's many problems with that code.

First, you need to pass your `$con` arround, the `mysqli_query` function needs to know what connection you're referring to, check the [manual page for mysqli_query()](http://php.net/mysqli.query).

Then there's also the line `if ($dangerresult = $mysqli_query(...`, where you're referring to `mysqli_query` as a variable.

Also,

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
```

Is lacking a closing bracket, so the rest of the script is only executed **in case of error** (and it's a syntax error too).

Comment: Yeah that second part was just copied from a guide online for counting rows.

Comment: Tried it there and it didn't work. This is assuming you mean I had to write it like ...mysqli_query($con, $sql);

Comment: @Frustrated_Scotsman yes, that's how you correctly call `mysqli_query`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Still not working but slowly, slowly fixing errors. Can you tell I'm not a Web Dev student?